# How to upload npm tgz to nexus3

Tags: nexus

I need to setup a private nexus oss 3 for internal nodejs development for our company. The project dependencies have to be download from developer's computer and copy across to the private network, and then upload/publish to the private nexus instance.

We've write some scripts to pull all dependencies in .tgz format form the npm repo, and copied into the private network.

But how can I upload those .tgz files to the npm repo of my private nexus without using the GUI?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- You can upload using the UI; but you choose not to use this way.
- You can upload using the API; [see the docs](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/rest-and-integration-api/components-api)
- You can upload using `npm publish`; eg.`npm --registry=http://nxrm.local/repository/npm-hosted publish package.tgz`

Answer (score 3):

For someone who interest for a fast solution, here's my procedure and scripts:

1. create a hosted npm repo in nexus
2. create an account for package upload
3. grant 'npm Bearer Token Realm' realm to the account
4. run the download script for download packages from public npm repository
5. run the upload script for upload packages to private npm repository

---

## script for downloading npm packages from public repository

```sh
#!/bin/bash

NODE_MODULES_PATH=./node_modules
PACKAGES_PATH=./packages

mkdir -p $PACKAGES_PATH

for url in $(grep _resolved $NODE_MODULES_PATH/**/package.json | awk -F '"' '{print $4}' | sort -u); do
    if wget -c -q "$url" -P $PACKAGES_PATH; then
        echo "url=$url"
    else
        (>&2 echo "error download url=$url")
    fi
done
```

---

## script for uploading npm packages to private nexus npm repository

```sh
#!/bin/bash

REPOSITORY=[REPOSITORY_URL]
PACKAGES_PATH=./packages

npm login --registry=$REPOSITORY

for package in $PACKAGES_PATH/*.tgz; do
    npm publish --registry=$REPOSITORY $package
done
```

---

Note:

- the packages have to be downloaded locally in the normal way
- the script should be running in the project root directory
- the [REPOSITORY] can be obtained in your private hosted npm repository

Comment: The `npm login` part was missing from the accepted answer.  This is a very complete solution, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the rest API to manage components directly:

```
POST ​/v1​/components
```

For instance, to upload the package `my-npm-package-0.0.0.tgz` to the repository `npm-private` use the following:

```
curl -u user:password -X POST "http://localhost:8081/service/rest/v1/components?repository=npm-private" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "npm.asset=@my-npm-package-0.0.0.tgz;type=application/x-compressed"
```

The complete live API specs can be found at endpoint `/#admin/system/api`

The official nexus documentation can be found at https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/rest-and-integration-api/components-api